# Why the custom font is not changed according to my setting?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-text

I have already imported the `SOV_Assadong_C.tff` file to my project using SwiftUI library. Plus, I added `SOV_Assadong_C.tff` value under the **Fonts provided by application** key in Information property list:

[image]

When I used the below code, the text still showed the system font.

```
Text("Hello")
   .font(.custom("SOV_Assadong_C", size: 70))
   .foregroundColor(fontColor)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What platform are you targeting? For macOS, you should use `ATSApplicationFontsPath` instead of `UIAppFonts`

Answer (score 2):

### Xcode 14.3 beta 1 (target iOS 16.4)

Drag-and-drop your `.ttf` font into the Navigator pane (don't forget to add it to the target).

[image]

Add the `.ttf` extension to your custom font name in the project's Info tab. Restart Xcode.

[image]

DO NOT use `.ttf` extension in your code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Phantasmagoria")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(.black)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.custom("SOV_Assadong_C", size: 120))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]